# Time Function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation in which the following code is being used by me to obtain a

time in hh:mmAM(Pm)  :

```
RTRIM(STUFF(right(convert(varchar(26),start_time,109),15),7,7,''))
```

I am getting for 18:00 00 000 the following '  6:00PM'.

I need to get '06:00PM'.  I have tried to replace ' ' with '0' and it is not working.

Does someone have some guidance for me ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  First start by tagging which rdbms you are using sql-server, oracle, mysql! It is likley that searchign for how to format a time as hh:mm will turn up a question possibly even on SO that will answer your question.

Comment: If start_time is TIME not DATETIME then all you need is CONVERT. if it is DATETIME use DATEPART to get the time and then use CONVERT. there are plenty examples of both of these functions on the net. Also provide a sample data set if you want correct responses. The first two here are based off guesses of what's in your table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

select right(replace(convert(varchar(26),getdate(),100),' ','0'),7)